# multiple meta_queries mysql hangs

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Im using a wp_query 
I have a lot of parameters to compare so I have to use multiple meta_queries (12)

The query creates a large SQL statement that contains at least 12 INNER JOINS

This behavior makes the MYSQL server hang (even if the table is very small)

Is there a solution for that ?

Other than filtering the results with PHP ?

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => financing
    [posts_per_page] => 20
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => family_status
                    [value] => "נשוי"
                    [compare] => LIKE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => has_appartment
                    [value] => 1
                    [compare] => =
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [key] => gender
                    [value] => "זכר"
                    [compare] => LIKE
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [key] => occupational_status
                    [value] => "שכיר"
                    [compare] => LIKE
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [key] => min_in_bank_stage
                    [value] => 1
                    [compare] => <=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [key] => max_children
                    [value] => 2
                    [compare] => >=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [key] => minimum_monthly_income
                    [value] => 12222
                    [compare] => <=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [key] => min_age
                    [value] => 3
                    [compare] => <=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [key] => max_age
                    [value] => 3
                    [compare] => >=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [key] => mortgage_payment_min
                    [value] => 1222
                    [compare] => <=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [key] => mortgage_payment_max
                    [value] => 1222
                    [compare] => >=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [key] => other_payments_amount_min
                    [value] => 111
                    [compare] => <=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [key] => other_payments_amount_max
                    [value] => 111
                    [compare] => >=
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You say it makes the MySQL server "hang."  How long did you wait for results? Was the server truly hung or was it just satisfying your query very slowly?  What happens if you run the query on four of these criteria rather than a dozen?  What happens if you change out the `LIKE` comparisons to `=` comparisons?  (WP's wp_postmeta data structures are a little gnarly when used the way you are using them.)

Comment: The mysql process is hanged for several hours

Answer (score 0):

I have suggest you one example as per your result of post. So, you can try this code,

```html
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'financing',
    'posts_per_page' => '20',
    'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'family_status',
            'value'   => 'נשוי',            
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'has_appartment',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => 'EQUAL'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'gender',
            'value'   => 'זכר',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        continue added more array as per example....        
    )
);
$search_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$min_max_values = array();
if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
        $search_query->the_post();
        array_push( $min_max_values, get_the_ID() );
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Hope, you get it!!

Comment: Yes but this is what i wanted to aviod, i want a solution that will work with a query .. not PHP